# Line incomplete svg

Tags: jquery, svg, line, flexbox

I'm trying to create svg lines dynamically.
However, the line does not appear from the outset, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong.
Below is the code and jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelcb21/h9qx4ero/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .container{
        display:flex;
    }

    .divsvg{            
        width: 150px;
        position:relative;
    }

    svg{
      position:absolute;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      top:0px;
    }

    .table {
        border-collapse: collapse;      
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .td {
        border: 1px solid #000
    } 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container"> 
    <div>
        <table class='table'>
            <tr><td class='td'>Table 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td class='td' id="valueA">value A</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="divsvg">
        <svg>
            <line id="line" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0)"></line>
        </svg>  
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class='table'>
            <tr><td class='td'>Table 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td class='td' id="valueB">value B</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="out"></div>
<div id="in"></div>
<br>
<div id="log"></div>

<script>   
    var valueA= $("#valueA");
    var valueA_pos = valueA.offset();
    valueA_pos.right = valueA_pos.left + valueA.width();

    var valueB= $("#valueB");
    var valueB_pos = valueB.offset();   
    valueB_pos.right = valueB_pos.left + valueB.width();

    $('#line').attr({
      "x1": valueA_pos.right,
      "y1": valueA_pos.top,
      "x2": valueB_pos.left,
      "y2": valueB_pos.top
    });

    $( "#out" ).text( "outX: " + valueA_pos.right + ", outY: " + valueA_pos.top );
    $( "#in" ).text( "inX: " + valueB_pos.left + ", inY: " + valueB_pos.top );

    $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
      $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I just need to change the x1 and x2 for x1=0 and x2=150, because this are the dimensions of the css div class svg https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelcb21/h9qx4ero/3/

```
    $('#line').attr({
      "x1": 0,
      "y1": valueA_pos.top,
      "x2": 150,
      "y2": valueB_pos.top
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG sits between the two tables.  You should be drawing your line from x=0 in the SVG to x=svg.width.  However you are starting your line at x=table1.width in the SVG.